# Configure VSCode tasks on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, visual-studio-code

Having an issue when trying to run a bash script as a task in VSCode (1.38.1) on macOS (10.14.6). Using the integrated terminal the script runs as expected. However, when I run it as a VSCode task, the executing shell is apparently different, and I'm unsure how to configure it.

The task is as follows:

```
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "List files",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "source ./scripts/test_ls.sh",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
```

And the test_ls.sh script is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${BASH_VERSION}"
ls
```

I have configured the integrated terminal as follows (in settings.json):

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
```

When I run from the integrated terminal manually (using either of the commands 'bash' or 'source') it states the bash version as 3.2.57(1)-release and then lists files as expected, but if I run the task above the shell gives the following output:

```
> Executing task in folder sdc1-scoring: source ./scripts/test_ls.sh -r <

3.2.57(1)-release
./scripts/test_ls.sh: line 3: ls: No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127
```

which begs the question, if it's not running the script using bash, what is it using? And how can this be configured?

Comment: Replace `source` with `bash -c` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Biswapriyo. If I do that the task execution shell reports:

```/bin/bash: bash: No such file or directory```